# H2 java app not starting but working in debug

Tags: java, persistence, h2

I have this problem with my Java 8 + ControlsFX 2 app.
I'm using H2 database serverless, and everything works fine in run/debug from eclipse, but when I creare the runnable jar and start it i get this message

```
2015-07-02 15:29:23,535|JavaFX Application Thread|ERROR|GestioneProdottiView.<init>() Errore creazione tabella
    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException: 
    Exception Description: An exception was thrown while trying to load persistence unit at url: rsrc:../
    Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-30004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
    Exception Description: An exception was thrown while processing persistence.xml from URL: rsrc:../
    Internal Exception: java.net.MalformedURLException
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionLoadingFromUrl(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:100) ~[jar:rsrc:org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceArchive(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:616) ~[jar:rsrc:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.getPersistenceUnits(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:500) ~[jar:rsrc:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfoInArchive(JPAInitializer.java:178) ~[jar:rsrc:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfoInArchives(JPAInitializer.java:160) ~[jar:rsrc:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfo(JPAInitializer.java:141) ~[jar:rsrc:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:183) ~[jar:rsrc:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63) ~[jar:rsrc:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar!/:?]
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47) ~[jar:rsrc:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar!/:?]
        at com.cremonaufficio.appbarsangiorgio.backend.database.DaoBase.<init>(DaoBase.java:34) ~[rsrc:./:?]
        at com.cremonaufficio.appbarsangiorgio.frontend.prodotti.GestioneProdottiView.<init>(GestioneProdottiView.java:93) [rsrc:./:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_45]
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at com.cremonaufficio.appbarsangiorgio.frontend.main.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:18) [rsrc:./:?]
        at com.cremonaufficio.appbarsangiorgio.ApplicationRoot.start(ApplicationRoot.java:60) [rsrc:./:?]
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$52/1019606772.run(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/672080502.run(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/1955345122.run(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/1936897764.run(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method) ~[rsrc:./:?]
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/479808962.run(Unknown Source) [rsrc:./:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_45]
    Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException: 
    Exception Description: An exception was thrown while processing persistence.xml from URL: rsrc:../
    Internal Exception: java.net.MalformedURLException
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionProcessingPersistenceXML(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:118) ~[jar:rsrc:org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceXML(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:657) ~[jar:rsrc:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceArchive(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:614) ~[jar:rsrc:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceXML(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:655) ~[jar:rsrc:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceArchive(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:614) ~[jar:rsrc:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceXML(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:655) ~[jar:rsrc:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceArchive(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:614) ~[jar:rsrc:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.0.jar!/:?]
        ... 37 more
```

My persistence unit file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence 
    version="2.1" 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>com.cremonaufficio.appbarsangiorgio.backend.database.entity.ProdottoEntity</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:~/scanner/database/database" /><!-- ~/ -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="app" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="app1505" /> 
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>


</persistence>
```

I guess the problem is the url but even with ./ to point a folder next to jar, it's not working. Any guesses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what was the problem. It turned out to be how I generate the JAR: I had to choose to "Extract required libraries" and not just "Package required libraries".

Cheers.